# npm start hangs, does not sync changes (create-react-app on WSL)

Tags: node.js, reactjs, windows-subsystem-for-linux, wsl-2

I am new to web dev and am trying to follow the React tutorial. I have followed it successfully in the past on my machine. I am using Ubuntu 20.04 in WSL.

When I run:

npx create-react-app helloworld
cd helloworld
npm start

I get:

> helloworld3@0.1.0 start /mnt/d/ProgrammingProjects/helloworld

> react-scripts start

And it hangs there for about 5 minutes before the localhost opens. Once the localhost is open, it does not sync changes when I edit and save the App.js file.

I have tried completely uninstalling and reinstalling node and npm.

Comment: Do you happen to have npm/node installed in both Windows and WSL/Linux?  If so, see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63458916/11810933).

Comment: I did have it and tried uninstalling, that didn't work unfortunately. thanks though!

Comment: Have you rebooted at any point since trying it?  Sometimes the Windows->WSL localhost port mapping seems to break down, and I'm not quite sure why.  You don't *have* to reboot, but if you haven't, try a `wsl --shutdown` from PowerShell or cmd (after saving and exiting out of everything, of course).

Comment: Just as a point of reference, I did try your exact scenario on WSL2/Ubuntu 20.04 and the browser opened up to the react sample within a second or so.  Hot reloading/sync worked after editing as well.

Comment: thanks for testing that out. It seems better now, but I'll try also try shutting down wsl next time this happens.

Answer (score 1):

I was also having the problem with hot reloading in WSL2 . I tried almost every solution present on github , stackoverflow and where not . Trying to fix it from
CHOKIDAR_USEPOLLING=true to setting FAST_REFRESH = false in .env to changing network setting using netsh and what not for 2 days . finally decided to revert to WSL1.
I think it's because WSL 2 is running as a hyper-v virtual machine.
If you're using WSL2 you should revert to WSL1 for now.

```
wsl --set-version Ubuntu-18.04 1
```

Run the above command in Powershell. And check version of WSL after  using

```
wsl -l -v
```

if it's version 1 now  you are good to go.