# Npm/Node getting "/usr/bin/env: node: No such file or directory" on Ubuntu on WSL2 on Windows 10 error

Tags: node.js, linux, bash, ubuntu, windows-subsystem-for-linux

I have tried to add things to my $PATH,
I have tried
`ln -s /usr/bin/nodejs /usr/bin/node`

I first installed nodejs using nvm with
`curl -o- https://raw.githubusercontent.com/nvm-sh/nvm/v0.35.0/install.sh | bash`

I then ran nvm install -lts and it shows me I have v.14.16.0 installed, but then it says
"nvm is not compatible with the npm config "prefix" option: currently set to ""
Run `npm config delete prefix` or `nvm use --delete-prefix v14.16.0` to unset it."
When I try both of those commands, neither of them work. I've tried going into my .bash_profile, .bashrc, and .bashrc.bash files and I don't see anything I can change?

Please help!

Comment: Haven't seen that one myself.  But a common cause of `npm`/`node` issues on WSL is having the Windows version of `node`/`npm` installed and it getting picked up in the Windows path that WSL automatically appends during `init`.  If you have the Windows version installed, I'd recommend checking out [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63458916/11810933) to make sure that's not your problem.

Comment: The path didn't come through in the comments, but what does `which npm` show?

Comment: Thanks, what's interesting is I'm pretty sure my Linux path comes before my Windows path. My path is really long, and I'm pretty sure the problem lies in my PATH somewhere. I'm trying to figure out how to clean it up, but my terminal config files are a mess in general. My path is as follows: 

(I'm actually going to have to make a separate comment for my path, hah)

Comment: Sorry, I started to type my PATH and got distracted and sucked into looking through my bash environment config files while typing it! I have oh-my-bash installed so I was trying to figure out where exactly my environment PATH is set to figure out why my PATH is so long. Here is the answer to your question:

`which npm
/home/linuxbrew/.linuxbrew/bin/npm`

I neglected to mention that after using `curl` I then tried to use Homebrew package installer to clean up the mess I made.