# How do I force my Linux distro in WSL2 on Windows to use the Linux version of nvm and not the Windows version?

Tags: linux, nvm, wsl-2

I have nvm for Windows installed and when I do a `whereis nvm` when logged into my Pengwin Linux distro via WSL2 it shows it's using the binary on the Windows filesystem mount at `/mnt/c/Users/seefe/AppData/Roaming/nvm/nvm.exe`. This is despite also going through the Linux installation procedure for nvm, which I assumed would hide the Windows version.

It's the same with `gatsby-cli`. The problem is when in Linux Land, running nvm and gatsby is a chore because the response time for commands across file systems is too slow. What's the WSL environment strategy for ensuring any packages I install via npm when in Linux are installing and using the packages specifically on the Linux filesystem?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [I can't use the npm command on Windows 10 with WSL2 ON (ubuntu terminal)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63116206/i-cant-use-the-npm-command-on-windows-10-with-wsl2-on-ubuntu-terminal).  I know that's about npm and your question is nvm, but the solution should be the same.

Comment: So it's a system PATH issue? Still unsure where I need to alter this. Is it in .bashrc or do I need to add config settings via WSL? Editing system paths in Windows is easy but I'm a Linux noob so that's a source of editing confusion if I need to do it in .bashrc.

Comment: That link does help but still leaves me with questions. I don't want to disable interop completely, I just the situation where if I'm in the Linux distro and run a command that is also available in npm global packages under Windows, it should look first at the Linux file system and then at the Windows appended path.

Looking at .bashrc I'm unsure where the Windows path append is happening and also whether I should be asking this question in Linux on how to edit environment variables such as PATH? Anything to avoid cross filesystem sluggishness. Just typing gatsby takes 20 seconds to respond.

Comment: Ultimately the solution *is* going to be in the startup files in your shell (e.g. bash).  The Windows path is appended by its `/init` process as one of the first things during startup (before `.bashrc`).  And since it is *appended*, if something in your startup config *appends* to the path (e.g. `export PATH="$PATH":/path/for/nvm`), the Windows binary can take precedence.  If the path to the Linux app is *prepended* (e.g. `export PATH=/path/for/nvm:"$PATH"`), then the Linux app would be found first.

Comment: Working on the basis that the solution is to edit Linux $PATH I used ```printenv``` to get a list of Linux environment variables. The path looks like it's prioritising the Linux filesystem:

PATH=/home/seefer/.nvm/versions/node/v14.18.0/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games:/usr/lib/wsl/lib...

After which comes a host of Windows /mnt/ paths.

```NVM_DIR=/home/seefer/.nvm``` seems okay as do the other NVM_* variables. So why is ```whereis nvm``` telling me it's at a Windows /mnt/ path as mentioned in my question. All very confusing.

Answer (score 0):

Apologies for leading you in the wrong direction with [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63116206/i-cant-use-the-npm-command-on-windows-10-with-wsl2-on-ubuntu-terminal) originally.

After installing `nvm` again in a test WSL session (I usually use `n` myself) I see that Linux `nvm` is installed as a bash *function*, not as a binary.  This means that `whereis nvm` doesn't actually see it, since `whereis` only looks for *files*.

```
> type nvm | head -1
nvm is a function
```

Two things to note:

- When entered without a fully-qualified path (absolute or relative), the function will take precedence over a binary.  So as long as `type nvm` returns the function, you should be fine.

  And the fact that you mention (in the comments) that your path starts with `/home/seefer/.nvm/versions/node/v14.18.0/bin` means that the *Linux* `nvm` is working correctly and prepending the correctly activate directory to your path.

  If you are experiencing issues with `node` or `npm` after using the `nvm use` or `nvm install` commands, let us know.
- While `whereis nvm` finds `/mnt/c/Users/seefe/AppData/Roaming/nvm/nvm.exe`, you would have to actually run `nvm.exe` for it to run the Windows version.

There *is* one more thing to watch out for here, though, that is related to that [other answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63116206/i-cant-use-the-npm-command-on-windows-10-with-wsl2-on-ubuntu-terminal).

`npm` on Windows is a strange one, since it actually does ship with a *shell script* (even though it is for Windows) named `npm` that in turn calls the Windows `npm.exe`.  If you have Windows Node/NPM installed (and it sounds like you do), be careful that you always active the *Linux* version (so that it is prepended to the path) with the Linux nvm.

Otherwise you can get into issues with Windows `npm` trying to run under WSL/Linux.

Be careful with this.  As long as you have activated a node/npm installation with the Linux